# Connecting forms in php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a form which has details like `name`,`number`,`email`,etc... I have 3 forms like this.

So I have created a file called `form.php` which has the form and I am including it in my page.

Each of the form has some details that is not in the other forms like:

- One form has Number of slots while the other 2 don't have it.

I explicitly added the uncommon part of the form in each page differently as a form.

Now I have 2 submit buttons. So how do I avoid two buttons and connect the 2 forms as the data from the complete form? It has to added to a single table.

Comment: i tried javascript but i guess its not giving theproper result

Comment: You really should post the code of what you are doing and how it is-or-isn't working so that the folks of SO can look at it, find the problem and hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: i dont want to write the same form three times in 3 different pages as most of the data is same in all the forms .But by dividing the form ie 1.form.php 2.the one which is present on age.I dont know how do i send the data of the second form to the sql ...with one submit button

Comment: Form.php
<form method ="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
Contact :<input type="text" name="contact"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

THe index.php page

<?php include 'Form.php';  ?>
<form>
<select name="slots">
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

All the information obtained from the for is added to a sql table ...
For the data obt from the 2nd form i tried using UPDATE slots="" Where name=""...

Comment: You should edit your original post and put the code there -- (comments have a character limit anyways, so it looks like part of what you posted above has been cut off)

Comment: Edit your question and add your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use $_SESSION in the first 2 forms to get the data to the third form.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Then retrieve data from the session in the third form and place it as a hidden field.

Then the submit button on the last form will submit all the data i.e from the fields in the third form as well as the data carried from the first two forms.

Comment: It is also possible using cookies but I wouldnt recommend that. Sessions were meant to solve this type of problems and in my opinion its the best way. Also adding and retrieving session is very easy in PHP.